# CONVERT(DATETIME, DATETIME, 131)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I can't seem to figure this one out and tried searching stackoverflow.

I have two lines where I want to convert the date.  I didn't create these datatypes or tables and don't want to change the date types in case it messes something up.

I have one table where one of the columns is of type (datetime2(7), not null).
I have another table where the column is of type (datetime, null).

when I do a query they return a time (respectively) that looks like

```
2015-01-25 10:11:50.9050000

2015-01-19 10:24:42.323
```

The above is before I do any conversion or casting.

I'd like to convert the format of those to

dd/mm/yy hh:mi:ss:mmmAM

So I used the code below (respectively)

```
SELECT TagName, CONVERT(DateTime, EventStamp, 131) AS ConvertedTime
FROM ALMDB.dbo.Hist
```

and

```
SELECT TagName, CONVERT(DateTime, DateTime, 131) AS ConvertedTime
FROM ALMDB.dbo.Hist
```

But it doesn't seem to work.  It drops the ss (seconds) part and the month/day/year portion does't come out according to style 131.  Anyone know why?  It looks like below

```
25/01/2015 10:11 AM
19/01/2015 10:24 AM
```

I tried a bunch of way and it doesn't seem to work.  I'm running MS SQL server 2012 and just doing the query in SQL Server Manager Studio.

Comment: Well, you are converting to datetime instead of a `VARCHAR(25)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert to an output format, you want to convert *from* a `datetime` *to* a string.

Try this:

```
SELECT TagName, CONVERT(varchar(255), EventStamp, 131) AS ConvertedTime
FROM ALMDB.dbo.Hist
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code tries to convert from datetime to datetime, which isn't what CONVERT is meant to do. If you wish to control the string representation of a date in your output, convert to nvarchar instead: `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25), DateField, 131)`. If you'd like to change the default string representation of a datetime field on a per-session basis, use the `SET DATEFORMAT` command. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx